# mock export function and variable in react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to test if delete button is present. The files structure are as below:

//a.js

```
import b from './b';
const xyz = props => { 
  const {var1, var2, func1, func2} = b(props); 

  return(
    <Button buttonType='primary'onClick={func1}>Add</Button>
    {
        var2.length > 0 && <Button buttonType='negative' onClick={func2}>Remove</Button>
    }) }   export default xyz;
```

//b.js

```
const b= (props) => {

const { data } = props;
let [var1, setVar1] = useState(initialState);
let [var2, setVar2] = useState([]);
const func1 = async () => { //some data }
const func2 = async () => { //some data }

return { var1, var2, func1, func2}
}
export default b;
```

//a.spec.js

```
import xyz from './a';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

//I am trying to get delete button in this test case but it is failing because I couldn't mock the b file properly.

it('should display Delete button', () => {
        const { getByRole } = render(<xyz sdk={mockSk.app}/>);
        expect(getByRole('button', { name: 'Delete' })).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

I am not certain how to mock b file so I can have some dummy value in var2 in return. it will satisfy the condition in a.js to display the delete button.
the things that I have tried in test suites are :

```
const mockDeleteData = {
    data: [{
         userId: 1,
         id: 1,
         title: 'My First Album'
    }]
}
let mockSk = {
    app: {
        onConfigure: jest.fn(),
        getParameters: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({}),
        setReady: jest.fn(),
        getCurrentState: jest.fn()
    }
};
```

it('should display Delete button', () => {

```
1) jest.mock('./b'); //trying to mock b file but not sure how to assign dummy value to var2
//2) jest.spyOn(b, 'b.func1'); // trying random things to see if it is working.
3) b.mockResolvedValue({ // just checking if it returning this but it return undefined
         data: [
             {
                 userId: 1,
                 id: 1,
                 title: 'My First Album'
             },
             {
                 userId: 1,
                 id: 2,
                 title: 'Album: The Sequel'
             }
         ]
     });
   4) b.default.var2 = mockDeleteData; // returns undefined instead of mockdata
5)const b= require('./b');
    const handleClick = jest.spyOn(b, 'func1');
    handleClick.mockReturnValue(mockDeleteData);

        const { getByRole } = render(<xyz sdk={mockSk.app} />);
        expect(getByRole('button', { name: 'Delete' })).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern usually works for me.

```
import * as bModule from './b'

jest.spyOn(bModule, 'b').mockReturnValue(
  (_props) => ({var1: value1, var2: value2, func1: jest.fn(), func2: jest.fn()}
)
```

You may not need to include `var1`, `func1`, or `func2` in your mocked return object, if it doesn't cause your code to throw and you don't want to test them. You also don't need to include the `_props` input if you don't need that to set any return object.

I don't normally use `export default`, so you might first start with `export const b = (props) => /*...*/` and see if you get that working first.

Comment: I've made a change as per your suggestion but I am receiving an error in a.js when it tries to call b(props). the error is message:'(0 , b.default) is not a function'. I also remove export default and make export const b = ...